# R subset data according list

Tags: r, list, subset, tweets

I am working on Twitter dataset and I haven't figure out subsetting my data according list of hashtags.

df:

```
rowID                Hashtags
 1                   ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
 2                   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar,halkinbasbakanitokatta
 3                   kurdish,mahabad,justiceforfarinaz,kurdistan
 4                   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
 5                   anfal,halabja,kurdistan,kobani
 6                   onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
 7                   kurdistan
```

Hashtags are a character list

hashtag_list:

```
"onlarkonusurakpartiyapar" "kurdistan"
```

I tried this code but it didn't work for me;

```
new_df=df[df$Hashtags %in% hashtag_list,]
```

It can only give the subset of "onlarkonusurakpartiyapar" hashtag.
I know that it looks so simple but I couldn't figure out yet even though I have looked all posts in the site.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `df[grep(paste(hashtag_list, collapse='|'), df$Hashtags),]`  Looks like all the rows have either one of the elements in the 'hashtag_list'

Comment: If you need two subsets `lapply(hashtag_list, function(x) df[grep(x, df$Hashtags),])` in a list.

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you for your help. I tried your subset solution and it gave a large list. I need to create a data frame with rowID and hashtags. I tried to use as.data.frame( ) command but it gives this error message:              "Error in data.frame(list(tweet_created_at = numeric(0), hashtag_text = character(0)),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 537623, 23, 388964".  tweet_created_at = rowID

Comment: You may need `do.call(rbind, lapply(hashtag_list...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that modifies yours by distinguishing characters separated by a "," to be different hashtag, and saying that the row is a match if any of those hashtags are in your list.

## Your Data

```
df <- data.frame(
    rowID=1:8, 
    Hashtags=c(
        "ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar", 
        "onlarkonusurakpartiyapar,halkinbasbakanitokatta",
        "kurdish,mahabad,justiceforfarinaz,kurdistan",
        "onlarkonusurakpartiyapar",
        "anfal,halabja,kurdistan,kobani",
        "onlarkonusurakpartiyapar",
        "kurdistan",
        "this,willnot,befound"
    ), 
    stringsAsFactors=F
)
hashtag_list <- c("onlarkonusurakpartiyapar", "kurdistan")
```

## The Solution

```
find_ht <- function(hashtags, hashtag_list){
    sapply(strsplit(hashtags, split=","), function(x)any(x%in%hashtag_list))
}
```

## Implementation

```
find_ht(hashtags=df$Hashtags, hashtag_list=hashtag_list)
```

which returns ...

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

## Edit

To perform the subset, you simply need to ...

```
sub.index <- find_ht(hashtags=df$Hashtags, hashtag_list=hashtag_list)
df[sub.index,]
```

which returns

```
 rowID                                                     Hashtags
1     1 ogretmenemayistamujdehazirandaatama,onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
2     2              onlarkonusurakpartiyapar,halkinbasbakanitokatta
3     3                  kurdish,mahabad,justiceforfarinaz,kurdistan
4     4                                     onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
5     5                               anfal,halabja,kurdistan,kobani
6     6                                     onlarkonusurakpartiyapar
7     7                                                    kurdistan
```

Or, if you want the indices do `which(sub.index)`. To Specifically subset the `rowID`'s only, do `df[sub.index,"rowID"]`. In this case, both of those return `[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

Comment: Hi rbatt, thank you for help and it is giving a logical list but I need a subset that has rowID and Hashtags because of that I need to create a histogram according each hashtag's create time. The end data frame must have column1: created time and column2: onlarkonusurakpartiyapar or kurdistan (items according hashtag list)

Comment: @eabanoz in R, the logicals can be used to subset. I'll edit answer to demonstrate this in a couple ways.